# Accessing MySQL database on Openshift Redhat remotely using TOAD

Tags: php, toad, openshift

I have deployed an app on Openshift redhat cloud server. I want to use toad to remotely access my mysql database. I am new to toad and never configured it. I just want to know how can I set it up to access my openshift database? I can create ssh connection to the server using toad, but it requires password and openshift instead provides a private key file to log in to the server. Can anyone help me upon this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use port forwarding to get local access to your database. There's a good blog post on port forwarding here:
https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift

To get your database username and password, you can ssh into your app and look at the mysql-related environment variables.

```
$ ssh <uuid>@<appname>-<namespace>.rhcloud.com
[appname-namespace.rhcloud.com ~]\> export | grep MYSQL
```

You can find the ssh command listed on the app overview page in the console, under the "Want to log in to your application?" link, or by running the `rhc app show` command.

Comment: Thanks. I used the steps given in the post and then used TCP settings in TOAD to connect to mysql database

Comment: It seems to be a temporary solution. I have a standalone application which connects to the remote database and needs to be distributed. How do I solve that problem?

Comment: Thank you, it was perfect for me remotely connect OpenShift, with Navicat ;-)

Comment: I'm getting an error using rhc port-forward: Error trying to forward ports. You can try to forward manually by running:
ssh -N blabla@blabla.rhcloud.com

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use port forwarding to access the db remotely